# Limited wifi Tethering Facility

Tags: android, network-programming, tethering

I wanted to create a payment portal, where the offline users would connect to my store Hotspot and make online payments. However, due to obvious reasons, i would like the users to be able to connect to the payment portal only. Is there a way i could do a whitelisting (or Blacklisting) of the URLs to which the network packets are destined ? Is there possibility that source code of tethering could be modified and an application could be built upon it that would get the job done ? If yes, then can it be done without rooting the phone.

P.S - I don't want to use Proxy.

Comment: You can and should do it with router you use to share internet connection in store. It is not an issue for Android application.

Comment: As per the requirements of product, i can't do it at the router end. Could you suggest some way to do it at the application end ?